# adding gcc compiler to xcode 7.3.1

Tags: xcode, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

I'm trying to use the following compiling command in xcode:

```
g++ -o example.cc -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

How can I add g++ and the command to xcode?  I have the command line tools from apple developer installed.